# HTML Pictures Moving when internet browser stretched

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm having is that my pictures are moving when I start stretching the internet browser. It needs to be a specific width for all the pictures to be inline. I want to make it so my pictures stay inline regardless of how stretched the internet browser gets.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class = "scrolling">
   <div class = "quick-info"> <!--Start quick-info-->
     <div class="image"> <!--Start1-->
       <img src="http://d39ya49a1fwv14.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/0x600.jpg" height="340" width="250"/>
     </div>
    <div class="image"> <!--Start2-->
      <img src="http://gstylemag.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Lebron-James-2.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image"> <!--Start3-->
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
    </div> <!--End3-->
    <div class="image"> <!--Start4-->
      <img src="http://www.zooatlanta.org/media/image/panda_cubs2013_140402_meilun_meihuan_ZA_0769_600.jpg" height="340" width="257"/>
    </div> <!--End4-->
    <div class="image"> <!--Start5-->
      <img src="http://www.soflasun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/dog8.jpg" height="340" width="259"/>
    </div> <!--End5-->
 </div> <!--End of quick-info-->
 </div>
 </body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
.quick-info {
  background-color:#659CEF;
  height: 350px;
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.image {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  width: 257px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

The pictures used in this code are just temporary pictures I put up to make for this example. Any help will be really appreciated! I'm not an HTML pro so sorry if I didn't do something as per the HTML regulations but please do help me! I've been stuck on this for days.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your css with the following CSS

```
.quick-info {
  background-color:#659CEF;
  height: 350px;
  width:1600px;  
  font-family: Garamond;
  font-size: 16px;
}
div.scrolling {
  width:800px;
  overflow-x:scroll;/*not really needed but it made the fiddle easier to navigate*/
  height:350px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You need to define a width on your containers, and then the images will flow into line.

In my example (visible at http://jsfiddle.net/9f0rhe3w/ ) you can see that it flows side by side. Just make sure the width of .quick-info is always at least the width of all images displayed combined.

I added the overflow scroll, but you could also add a position `relative` to `.quick-info` and a `position:absolute` to `.scrolling`  and then move it with a timer to get a ticker tape.

Comment: Michael, is there any way to make it so if a user stretches his/her browser, the pictures just wont be affected? Like they would just remain static to the position regardless of the size of the browser

Comment: I modified my answer, Is that the behaviour you were looking for?

Comment: I'm looking more for if the user stretches the internet browser. Right now, if I stretch my internet browsers, the pictures get affected and are moved down whereas I want them to stay inline and not be affected at all if the user is stretching the browser

Comment: Aah, the question has become clear. I modfied my answer again. is this what you were looking for?